# build error with xtgmath.h and cmath

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed GLUT, and GLEW, and was running some OpenGL example code the other day.  I come back to my project and try to run some basic c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Come up and C++ me some time.";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "You won’t regret it!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and the file is C++.  Anyway, I get these errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testGlut1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(214): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(214): warning C4602: #pragma pop_macro : 'new' no previous #pragma push_macro for this identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(215): warning C4193: #pragma warning(pop) : no matching '#pragma warning(push)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(216): warning C4161: #pragma pack(pop...) : more pops than pushes
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asin'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceil'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'exp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floor'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmod'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(27): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(27): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(27): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(27): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pow'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sin'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tan'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceilf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'coshf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabsf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floorf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmodf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexpf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(36): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexpf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'logf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modff'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'powf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinhf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrtf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanhf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2l'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceill'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'coshl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabsl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floorl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmodl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexpl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(45): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexpl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'logl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10l'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modfl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'powl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(47): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinhl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrtl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanhl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(50): warning C4431: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C no longer supports default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cbrt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'erf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'erfc'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cmath(53): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: please write `using namespace std;` below `#include <iostream>` and outside `int main()`

Comment: unless you have programmed with opengl before, i would recommend learning C++ first.

Comment: @AntonD Yeah, you are right.  That's really what I was doing here in this example.  I dived into OpenGL, and then I retreated back to just C++.  I only stated that I installed GLUT and GLEW because I wasn't sure what the problem was.  Just setting up the compiler is really a chore.  Maybe I should just do a fresh install... Start over...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler processes your file as C. Specify that need to be compiled as C ++.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)